# Kann "Ehefrau" sächlich sein?

Tags: gender

Ich habe in einer Übersetzung von Strindbergs *Inferno* den folgenden Satz gefunden:

> Der Schuß hat getroffen. **Mein** Ehefrau antwortet mit der Scheidungsklage.

Was soll das? Das Buch habe ich physikalisch, nicht als Datei.

Comment: Ein Druckfehler?

Comment: Wegen des Frauenhasses des Ichs  dachte ich, dass *Ehefrau* sächlich  was anderes bedeuten könnte.

Comment: Vielleicht wurde _Weib_ erst spät durch _Frau_ ersetzt und das Pronomen nicht angepasst. Von wann ist die Übersetzung? (Im Original scheint das Buch erstmals 1897 erschienen zu sein.)

Comment: @Crissov: Die Übersetzung von Morgenstern ist von 1898.

Comment: @Takkat: Wenn der Text bei Morgenstern _anders_ lautet, sagt das doch gerade nichts über die c.p. vorliegende Übersetzung aus, oder? Die könnte 1897, 1947, 1997 oder sonstwann erschienen sein.

Comment: Hi, @Crissov bin nicht zu Hause um mir das Buch genauer anzuschauen, aber von dem, woran ich mich erinnere, war das Buch von der Sammlung Dieterich und dementsprechend nach kurzem Googeln von 1991.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In der Übersetzung von Christian Morgenstern liest sich der betreffende Absatz wie folgt:

[image]

> Der Hieb sitzt. Meine Frau antwortet mit einer Klage auf Scheidung.

Diese Übersetzung findet sich bis heute in den meisten Auflagen von Strindbergs Inferno.

Wenn andere Übersetzer andere Worte finden, mag das eine Bereicherung sein, aber ein fehlendes 'e' im Possessivpronomen *meine* ist definitiv ein **grammatikalischer Fehler**, der sich wahrscheinlich über das schwedische Original

> *Skottet har träffat. **Min hustru** svarar med en ansökan om skilsmässa.*

eingeschlichen hat, an das sich das Beispiel aus der Frage auch im Übrigen fast wörtlich hält.

Answer (score 6):

Wie chirlu sagt, könnte es ein Druckfehler sein - denn wie Colin sagt, ist "Ehefrau" immer weiblich.

Eine andere Möglichkeit wäre, dass der Übersetzer versucht, Dialekt oder Register wiederzugeben. Spricht derjenige, der diesen Satz sagt, Dialekt? Oder soll sprachlich angedeutet werden, dass er nicht der Oberschicht angehört? Dann könnte sein, dass der Übersetzer ihn das "e" verschlucken lässt:

> ... Mein' Ehefrau antwortet mit der Scheidungsklage.

Bei (vor allem älteren) Übersetzungen stolpert man manchmal über die eigenartigsten Sachen...